# UI pattern for multiple destinations from UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

I'm trying to find the right UI pattern for connecting a list of items in a UITableView to a choice of destinations. In a UITableView I have a list of food items. I want the user to be able to select one of them and then either see a list of ingredients or to see nutritional information for that food item.

The best approach I can think of is to use a Tab Bar Controller where the first view is the list of ingredients. If the user has selected one food item, depending on which other tab they tap on they go to either the ingredients or nutritional information for that specific food item. But that doesn't seem like an appropriate use of a Tab Bar Controller, which typically shows different views that are not so directly related.

Another UI approach I can think of is to expose disclosure indicators for the food item cells and somehow make a long-press on the selected UITableView row display a pop-up menu that allows the user to select the desired destination. But A) it won't be obvious to a user that a long-press gesture will do something, B) it's not clear what a simple short press should do (and it would be non-intuitive for it to do nothing), and C) I'm not sure how to implement the pop-up choice in this case anyway. So my conclusion is there must be a better way.

How can this be done in a way that is consistent with iOS UI conventions?

Comment: I can suggest a way in which you just perform simple navigation and show a new screen upon selection any cell from tableView. That new screen can include a segmented control with titles like "Ingredients" and "Information" and user can switch between 2 screens to show Ingredient and nutritional information.

Comment: Second approach would be you can show both those information in a single screen which will be shown as similar as first approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I settled on was to have UITableView that displays the list of food items, where selecting one of the items segues to another UITableView with three sections:

1. A 'label' view with a summary of the item that was selected. In my case it includes an UIImage of the food. The point is to show the user which item the selected.
2. A section showing the ingredients
3. A section showing the nutritional information

The benefit of this approach is that it also works well in a splitViewController.